# Problems configuring a managed switch with my laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, switch

I'm currently doing some work for my uni's lab, and part of it includes trying to use a managed switch (TL-SG105E) as an intermediary between a raspberry pi and a stepper motor. I'm currently trying to set up said switch by accessing the web-based GUI it's said to come with, but I'm running into problems connecting to that.

I first connected the switch via ethernet to the lab's network, and then connected my own personal laptop to the network as well (also with ethernet) and tried to interface into the switch from there by typing in the switch's default IP address into my browser (192.168.0.1.), but no dice. I then noticed the switch's MAC address was stickered on the back of it, so I also tried "arp -a" in command prompt to see if that would give me anything, but I couldn't see the MAC address in the rather short list I was given.

As a last ditch attempt, I tried to connect my laptop to the switch manually with an ethernet cable between them, but that didn't allow a connection either.

I'm rather new to networking, so I'm not sure if there's something obvious in the process that I'm missing; if someone could enlighten me to what I'm doing wrong or to what else I could try to connect, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Have you checked with your uni's network team? Do they do validation or security on their network ports to control what can be connected? Do you know that what you are doing is a supported configuration? What happens when you connect your laptop to the switch in question rather than to the upstream network?

Comment: @music2myear I haven't checked with the lab's network manager, but I will do that. And I'm pretty sure computer --> router --> switch is supported, or at least it seems to be based on the manual (https://static.tp-link.com/res/down/doc/TL-SG108E_V2_IG.pdf). When you say connect my laptop to the switch, do you mean just by putting the two together with an ethernet cable?

Comment: @electricnerd What's your computer's IP address and subnet mask when connected to the lab's network? What's the default subnet mask for the new managed switch?

Answer (score 1):

To talk to another IP address directly over an isolated Ethernet LAN, your computer must have an IP address on the same subnet as the IP address of the device you're trying to reach. Your switch's IP address of 192.168.0.1 suggests that it's on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet. So to talk to that switch, you will need to give your computer's Ethernet interface an IP address on that subnet, such as 192.168.0.2/24 (the /24 means a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0).